# vue.js, how to load directive before page is loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a directive that controls what buttons someone can see based on their user role:

```
import { store } from '../store/';
import * as types from '../store/types';

const hide = vnode => {
  if (vnode.elm.parentElement) {
    vnode.elm.parentElement.removeChild(vnode.elm);
  }
};

export const userRole = {
  update(el, binding, vnode) {
    const userId = store.getters[types.GET_USER_ID];
    const { value, modifiers } = binding;
    if (value.role) {
      if (Reflect.has(modifiers, 'manager')) {
        if (value.role[0] !== userId) hide(vnode);
      }
};
```

Then I'll have a button like this:

```
          <vue-button
            v-userRole.manager="{role: job.role}"
            @click.prevent.stop="e => payoutJob(job.id)"
          >
            Button Text
          </vue-button>
```

All the buttons will show on the page before the user directive loads. So tons of buttons flash on the page. And then 2 seconds later only two buttons show, as that is what they have permission to see. How do I prevent this?

I would want at the very least, no buttons to appear on the page until the logged in user is matched against the user role directive file.

User information is stored in location storage, in vuex and every page that loads checks for a signed in user.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have created this I think means that this will always happen - your directive is removing the HTML only after it has been created.  For the element not to have been created in the first place you need instead to use a `v-if` or similar.  I can see two ways to fix this, one a work-around as a minimal change to what you have, the other I would consider a better solution (but it is of course up to you).

To work around your problem have all of your buttons with a style of `display:none` and then in your directive either delete the elemet or clear the style (or change the class - however you choose to implement it).  That way at least the button won't appear.

However, a better fix, I think, is to create your own component with a `userRole` property.  That component will then do the check you have above (for example through a computed property) and then show or hide the component as required.

---

EDIT

I ran a quick [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enms7b0g/1/) to test the principals behind what you were doing - just changing the hook from `update` to `inserted` may fix it.  Obviously your code will be more complex so your milage may vary ;).

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on Vue instance - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html - I think you might use beforeCreate.

Also another idea as Euan Smith wrote, use v-if and put in your data true/false information of loading rights (set it false, and when the role is known set it to true).